# How to convert afnetworking json dictionary to string and then convert the string to a dictionary in IOS?

Tags: ios, json, afnetworking

I am getting the json response as a dictionary. I want to save the response in the core data and the retrive the response from core data later when i required. So i am just converting the dictionary to a string as stringWithFormat and saving it. But when i am retrieving it, i am unable to convert to to dictionary. Any kind of help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say what you are trying is misguided.

You shouldn't use CoreData to store strings. You should use CoreData as it should be used, as a relational database. Create tables, then take the JSON dictionary to fill these tables the way they should be filled.

That said: The class NSJSONSerialization has a method to turn an array or dictionary into NSData, and a method to turn NSData into an array or dictionary. So to create your string, turn your NSDictionary into NSData, create an NSString from it, store the string. To turn the string back to an NSDictionary, create an NSData object from it, use NSJSONSerialization to turn it into a dictionary. Best to use UTF-8 string encoding both times.

Answer (score 0):

The appropriate way to save the dictionary to core data is to create NsManagedObject wrt to the json 
structure and than save in coredata.

But if you have different requirement than save ot as NsData not as NsString.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just get your response as a JSON string save that string and then convert it to an NSDictionary when you need it.